# How to update state using LocalStorage in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have an array that fetches API data every time componentDidMount() is called. I have an object with a default boolean value of true pushed to each element in the array. An onClick function has been set up so that when the specific element is clicked, the boolean value for it is changed to false and the array is placed in localStorage.

I need the data array to continuously refresh every time the page is reloaded so I have a check in my componentDidMount() method that just receives the boolean value from the array I just saved in localStorage.

Although this works, the boolean values are assigned based on index and not for the element itself. The problem here is that if the element "A" in position 2 was originally set to false and was then to swap with element "B" in position 3 following another API call, the boolean values would then be incorrect as "B" would now be false and "A" would now be true.

```
import React from 'react';
import StarBorder from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder';
import Star from '@material-ui/icons/Star';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {

            axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true')
            .then(res => {
                const data = res.data;

                const fromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('test');

                if (localStorage.getItem('test')) {
                  const dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(fromLocalStorage);
                  this.setState({ data: data.map((x, i) => ({...x, starIcon: dataFromLocalStorage[i].starIcon }))})
                } else {
                 this.setState({ data: data.map(x => ({...x, starIcon: true}))})
                }

            }) 
    }

    handleClick = (n) => {

        this.setState(prevState => ({
          data: prevState.data.map((x) => (x === n ? {
            ...x,
            starIcon: !x.starIcon
          } : x))
        })
        , () => {
          localStorage.setItem('test', JSON.stringify(this.state.data));
        });

      }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Rank</td>
                    <td>Icon</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Price</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map((n, i) => {
                    return (
                        <tr>
                        <td>{n.market_cap_rank}</td>
                        <td> <span onClick={() => this.handleClick(n)}> {n.starIcon ? <StarBorder/> : <Star /> } </span> </td>
                        <td>{n.name}</td>
                        <td>{n.current_price}</td>
                        </tr>
                    );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-fog-7yplb

If you were to change for example item in position 40 called "Algorand" by clicking true to false that work as expected. The API call however would refresh the rest of the data, and "Algorand" might no longer be in position 40 but the boolean value in position 40 would still be false and not mapped to "Algorand"

Comment: Can you please create a working example for this?

Comment: Do you want me to link a codesandbox?

Comment: yes a codesandbox would work.

Comment: Give the element a key (i.e., n.name) then pass that to handleClick() to store with the value?

Comment: you are checking x === n which are objects. Try x.id === n.id   Though I always find no 40 to be Algorand. May be you can check if the change works when the order changes.

Comment: I think the biggest concern here is that you are checking a whole object where you would be better to send the `market_cap_rank` back `onClick` and you can do a strict equality. It’s the only value that is unique to the view but different to the inbound data.

Comment: Could you help me out with the implementation of that strict equality check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this in your componentDidMount

```
const fromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("test");

if (localStorage.getItem("test")) {
          const dataFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(fromLocalStorage);
          let updatedData = data.map((d) => {

            const result = dataFromLocalStorage.find( dfls => dfls.id === d.id );
            return {...d, starIcon: result.starIcon} ;
          })
          this.setState({
            data: updatedData
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({ data: data.map(x => ({ ...x, starIcon: true })) });
        }
```

What I have done here is when you map refreshed data in your state, Instead of matching the whole object(which wont work correct), I have find the correct object from the array and use the startIcon from it.

Comment: If the only dependent value is your startIcon, you can just add only the id (if it is your unique identifier) and the starIcon value. It makes no sense storing whole object with so much data in local storage.

Comment: I would only store the objects for which I mark false(or change). So if the result of .find is not found I would just directly add the object.